# Did Vince Foster take his own life?

Tags: united-states, media

The website [TruthOrFiction](https://www.truthorfiction.com/clintonfriends/) writes:

> Vince Foster was Deputy White House Counsel and the Clinton’s lawyer.  He was found dead in Fort Marcy Park on July 20, 1993. Three investigations into Foster’s death, including one by Independent Counsel Kenneth Starr, have concluded that the death was a suicide.  Critics of the investigations say Foster’s death does not fit the facts of a suicide and that there are a lot of unanswered questions about his death, some of the activities at the White House after his body was found, and the investigations themselves.  Although there are numerous theories about what may have happened to Foster and why, none of them has been proven.

According to a [poll](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/06/01/half-of-georgia-trump-voters-think-hillary-murdered-vince-foster-poll-trolls-find.html) half of Trump wroters think Clinton had involvement in Vince Foster death:

> The data, released Wednesday, found that half of pro-Trump voters polled believe Clinton had “some involvement” in the death of Vince Foster, who once served as a Deputy White House Counsel during Bill Clinton’s presidency. 13 percent of respondents said Hillary Clinton did not, in fact, help kill a lawyer, and 37 percent were not “sure one way or another.”

[TheWashingtonPost](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/05/24/yes-there-actually-are-people-who-believe-the-clintons-killed-vince-foster/) writes:

> The latest thing Donald Trump is talking about not talking about is the 1993 death of White House attorney Vince Foster, which was ruled a suicide by multiple investigations but which "people" — according to Trump — believe was a murder orchestrated by the Clintons.

Does Foster's death fit the facts of him killing himself?

Comment: There's no claim here: "Although there are numerous theories about what may have happened to Foster and why, none of them has been proven."

Comment: @Sklivvz : There is the statement that critics claim that it wasn't a suicide. I think "It wasn't a suicide" is a claim even in the absence of an alternative story of what happened.

Comment: Can you find an actual example of that claim? The site only claims that other people claim it wasn't a suicide.

Comment: Presidential candidate Donald Trump claimed that Foster's death was "very fishy".  Example of a source that also disputes it:  http://www.wnd.com/2016/05/trumps-vince-foster-attack-backed-by-new-evidence/  Also, according to Public Policy Polling, half of Trump voters in Georgia think that Clinton had "some involvement" in Foster's death:  http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/06/01/half-of-georgia-trump-voters-think-hillary-murdered-vince-foster-poll-trolls-find.html

Comment: @Sklivvz : I added a quote from the poll that Brythan posted in his comment. I think the question should now be specific enough and demostrate that the claim that Foster didn't commit suicide is notable.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. On the other hand, "some involvement" or "very fishy" are not factual claims, and are especially not claims that the suicide was faked. Putting psychological pressure on Foster certainly could qualify as "some involvement", but that does not mean he did not commit suicide.

Comment: @Sklivvz : Okay I added an additional link.

Comment: What does it mean for a death to "fit the facts" of something? Is asking did a death "fit the facts of killing himself" the same as asking "did he kill himself" and letting the evidence come through?

Comment: @Dawn : Asking "Are the known facts consistent with theory X" is asking whether a weaker question than asking "Do the known facts prove theory X".

Comment: Okay, buy in either case, answers will just provide the evidence, so I don't think the more complicated wording is needed.

Comment: @Dawn : I usually put a simple wording on top of a question as headline, then I quote sources and then I finish with a precise wording of what I'm asking. Sometimes I also add an additonal sentence to the end to cover a few SEO keywords.

Comment: I am just unfamiliar with the phrase "did [a situation] fit the facts of X"... Maybe I'll ask at [English.se].